# Animating the UI screens of an app for Portfolio

Tags: interface-design, animation, portfolio

Can anyone be open to suggest their procedure of representing their UI work of a mobile or web app on Behance or any other platform they upload?

I want to know **whether you create a GIF** or just **record the slides animation** and upload it as a video?

Could all prototyping, designing and making GIF could be done from **one tool** or have to use different tools to do them?

Answer (score 2):

I would make the wild generalization that animated GIFs are the most common method to share animated snippets of UI work.

GIFs are extremely common in Behance case studies, and a ton of work showcased on Dribbble are animated GIFs. Not to mention they're are typically smaller file size than videos, and there are plenty of free tools on the web to convert video to GIF.

As for an all-in-one designing / prototyping / sharing tool, I would recommend [Flinto](https://www.flinto.com) for Mac. The experience is quite similar to Sketch (you can even import your Sketch files), it has incredible transition and behavior animation capabilities, and you can export a recording of your prototype to a video or GIF all from within the app.

There are plenty of designing/prototyping apps out there. Some popular ones would include [InVision Studio](https://www.invisionapp.com/studio) and [Framer X](https://framer.com), but I cannot speak to their exporting features. I would just start with the free trials and see which you like best.